# What claims should I verify in JWT token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

Should I verify issuer and audience?

If I verify only an issuer, the sender could be someone who is authorized to another apps? If I verify only an audience, the sender could be someone who is authorized the same name app but issued by a different issuer (that means a different app)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should validate both if both are present.

You should always verify the issuer attribute is what you expect. The two uses of the issuer field in the token are to provide a namespace for the user identity claim and a reference to the right verification key if you accept multiple issuers as valid for your service. So in some circumstances (one issuer trusted and the signature checks out) you might feel you don't technically need to read the issuer field. But it is part of the signed data, and you know what it *should* be, so validating it is better from a cryptographic security standpoint.

If the audience is given in the token, you should respect it. If the issuer intends you to only use the identity for a specific service, and you aren't that service, then something is wrong with the application or the user's intent. In that circumstance, you are much better off not accepting the token. But if the audience is not provided and you trust the issuer, it shouldn't be a problem to accept the token.